# beamer subfloat number alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats

I want the letter to align exactly with the images(little righter). Here is my code

```
\begin{figure}
        \subfloat[\label{fig1}]{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.74]{varnode.pdf}}\qquad \qquad 
        \subfloat[\label{fig2}]{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.74]{checknode.pdf}}
\end{figure}
```

and here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've inserted a spurious space as part of the image placement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[\label{fig1}]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}\qquad \qquad 
  \subfloat[\label{fig2}]{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note how (a) has a mis-aligned placement, while (b) is perfectly centred. That's because of the use of `%` around the line-break inside the `\subfloat`. Without it, there's actually an extra space set *before* the image, pushing it over slightly to the right (i.e., pushing the caption over slightly to the left).

For more on this topic, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)